# Adobe Flash Player / Flex select speakers

Tags: flash, apache-flex

Is there a way to select the used loudspeakers from Adobe Flex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not via code, or existing APIs.  If you're running an AIR app you may be able to write a Native Extension to select the sound output device; as this is something done at the operating system level.